# div element not changing on submit - jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$('#form_id').submit(function()
{
    $('#right').load("view.php");
});
```

This is my js code. This code should load the view.php into div element with ID right. The form ID is form_id.

It div displays when the below line is put without any function, like:

`$('#right').load("view.php");` //without submit function

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try trigger event submit on form.

```
$("#form_id").bind('ajax:complete', function() {
    $('#right').load("view.php");
});
```

or bind event first

```
$('#form_id').submit(function()
{
    $('#right').load("view.php");
});
```

Comment: when I put `alert("asd");` in the place of `$('#right').load("view.php");` it's working.
but the load script is not working.help pls!!

Comment: Are you using Submit form by Ajax? Maybe the page is reloading so that $('#right').load('view.php') not working.